# I want to make a call in php that will create an <li> for each post?

Tags: php, wordpress, html-lists

I'm trying to get this layout:

```
<ul>
<li>post1</li>
<li>post2</li>
<li>post3</li>
</ul>
```

I want each post to create a new `li` using PHP and WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the wordpress documentation. This should get you started:

```
<ul>
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'offset'=> 1, 'category' => 1 );

$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>

</ul>
```

And for further reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Posts_list_with_offset